# Gravity view plugin not showing all data in edit mode

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

Currently, I am working on a PHP code in which I am using "Gravity View" plugin. I added all fields using the "Gravity Forms" plugin & to view & edit I am using "Gravity View" plugin. I have a page as named "Profile" in which user can able to view & edit details, but all the fields are not displayed in edit mode. I got stuck from long, any help will be appreciable.

Comment: Please show us your code, otherwise how can we help?

Comment: @Mikkel I am using "plugin". Everything is managed by plugin but there are some settings which I don't know by using which this issue can be handled.

Comment: The question is out of scope for Stack Overflow. We will help you with coding problens